# Exception handling method to use with CompleteableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a few static methods that have signature as follows:

```
public static void produceMessages() throws AeventException,
    ResourceUnavailableException {...}
```

or

```
public static void doFunnyStuff(SolrIndex solrIndex) throws DifferentException {...}
```

I want to wrap all those methods in `WebApplicationException` which is `RuntimeException` so I can use them with  `CompletableFuture.runAsync()`.

So far got something like this:

```
private void handleExceptions(Runnable r) {
    try {
        r.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception occured", e);
        throw new WebApplicationException(
            Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity("Internal error occurred").build());
    }
}
```

But I still cannot use those methods as I want to:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            handleExceptions(() -> PromotionEventProducer.producePromotionUpdateMessages());
        });
```

this unfortunately still prompts me to use try/catch inside the `runAsync` block. What's the best way to implement such method that transforms all exceptons to runtime exceptions that one can use with `CompleteableFuture`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot throw a checked exception from a lambda expression, the same rule applies for `handleExceptions(() -> ...)`, which is a lamda expression itself.

However, you can define an interface that looks similar to `Runnable` but throws an exception.

```
interface RunnableWrapper {
    void run() throws Exception;
}
```

Then you can define a method which converts the checked excpetion to a runtime exception.

```
public void handleException(RunnableWrapper r) {
    try {
        r.run();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new CompletionException(e);
    }
}
```

Your final statement will then look like this, where `foo` is a method that throws a checked excpetion.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> handleException(this::foo));
```